# PHP Class linking

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, extends

I have an issue with classes and childs.

Right now I have it like this (my Core class)
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8fb344e9743284a5b12b

Note line 37-41. Those classes are extending core.
Now pay attention to 51-74.

This works flawless, if I'm calling everything from, let's say, index.php with $core = new Core;
$core->db()->query("blablabla"), but it does not work, for example, if I'm calling it from another class, which extends this Core. $this->db()->query("blablabla") simply does not work.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question itself.  You shouldn't link to code hosted externally.

Answer (score 1):

If you're overriding the constructor in the child classes, you'll need to explicitly call the parent constructor from the child constructor.  Otherwise, those properties will never be initialized.

```
class Child {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what should I do if I want these classes globally, without re-initializing them from child?

Comment: Instance properties are unique to each instance.  If you want, for example, every `db` property to refer to the same db, then you'll need a dependency injection layer or a factory / singleton creation setup.